# URL definition for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I have got following code block to open mail application with no problem before iOS9.

```
    let ss = "device information"
    let s = "mailto:feedback@stackoverflow.com?subject=Feedback%20for%20Example%20App&body=\(ss)"
    let url = NSURL(string : s)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

Now I get this Error : LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme mailto.

What should insert into info.plist/LSApplicationQueriesSchemesto make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Start by [searching on LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LSApplicationQueriesSchemes).

Comment: Still unclear. Update your question with what you tried and explain what problems you had. And please stop adding unnecessary tags to your question.

Comment: It is about LSApplicationQueriesSchemes which is used to define your URLs. If the URL is not defined in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes openURL does not open the link. This is came along with iOS9. So if you have a legacy code that used to openURL to open a link or another app, it would not work anymore. I believe it is a pain in the neck for many people already.

Comment: I know what it is for. I'm suggesting that you need to clarify what help you need with it. There are plenty of example in the search I referenced. But you said they didn't help. So I suggested that you update your question with what you tried. Or at least explain in what way the others didn't help.

Comment: If you are trying this on the simulator it will not work, try it on the real device or use MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Thank you Zirk! That was the case. But it is quite misleading since the function used to work on ios 8 simulator.